# Python, Kivy. How to disable/enable a button?

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible to disable the **'Result'** button when `#1 (TextInput)` or `#2 (TextInput)` or both `(TextInput)` are empty and enable the button when both TextInput are filled?
I found and tried '`disabled: True`' in `.kv` file but then I am stuck and I can't figure it out how to make it work.

I've created a simple code to show you what I want to achieve:

My file `.py`:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class test(BoxLayout):
    first = ObjectProperty()
    second = ObjectProperty()
    result = ObjectProperty()

    def result_final(self):
        x = int(self.first.text)
        y = int(self.second.text)

        z = x * y

        self.result.text = str(z)


class firstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return test()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    firstApp().run()
```

My file `.kv`:

```
<test>:

    first: first_number
    second: second_number
    result: result_number

    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 20
    spacing: 20

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "#1"
        TextInput:
            id: first_number
            input_filter: "int"

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "#2"
        TextInput:
            id: second_number
            input_filter: "int"

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'RESULT'
            on_press: root.result_final()


    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: result_number**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is easy to do with a bit of logic in your `kv`. Use this for your `Result` `Button`:

```
    Button:
        text: 'RESULT'
        disabled: True if first_number.text == '' or second_number.text == '' else False
        on_press: root.result_final()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I wanted to create! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Test(BoxLayout):
    first = ObjectProperty()
    second = ObjectProperty()
    result = ObjectProperty()
    result_btn = ObjectProperty()
    empty = True

    def check(self):
        if self.first.text.strip() != '' and self.second.text.strip() != '':
            self.result_btn.disabled = False
        else:
            self.result_btn.disabled = True

    def result_final(self):
        x = int(self.first.text)
        y = int(self.second.text)

        z = x * y

        self.result.text = str(z)


class FirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FirstApp().run()
```

and .kv

```
<test>:

    first: first_number
    second: second_number
    result: result_number
    result_btn: result_btn
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 20
    spacing: 20

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "#1"
        TextInput:
            id: first_number
            input_filter: "int"
            on_text:
                root.check()

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "#2"
        TextInput:
            id: second_number
            input_filter: "int"
            on_text:
                root.check()

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            id: result_btn
            text: 'RESULT'
            on_press: root.result_final()
            disabled: True if root.empty else False


    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: result_number
```

Basically, everytime you type in any number you call a check() method which chcecks if both of the inputs are empty.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a longer method but I like this too! :)